# Need a Regex Expression in iOS, I have the expression like ^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{8-32}[<>%\*])$

Tags: ios, regex

I need a regex expression which should satisfy the following rules :

1. Must be between 8-32 characters long
2. Must begin with a letter
3. Must not contain any spaces
4. Must not contain any special characters

I tried my own expression with the help of google like `^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{8-32}[<>%\*])$`  but this is throwing me an error like "Can't do regex matching, reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL "

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope you're not going to use this to enforce a password policy.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{7,31}$
```

This only allows characters A-Z, a-z, and the numbers 0-9, which automatically excludes spaces and special characters.

The explanation:

- `^[A-Za-z]` means that it must start with a letter, either A-Z or
  a-z. The `^` symbol indicates the start.
- `[A-Za-z0-9]{7,31}$` means that after the first rule is satisfied, there must be between 7 and 31 characters that are numbers or letters, after which we must reach the end; the `$` indicates the end. If you have other characters you want to allow, you can add them to the first set of brackets, just don't forget to escape anything that needs it (such as `*`).

Also notice that I used {7,31} to indicate 7 to 31 repetitions with a comma, not a dash as you have in your sample code. This is the reason you get the `U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL` error: intervals are expressed with `{}` and a comma.